# C++20 <chrono> incomplete type used in nested name specifier

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20, c++-chrono, libstdc++

Now that [GCC 11](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-11/changes.html#:%7E:text=Calendar), which supports the [new calendar and time zone features](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0355r7.html) is released, I am trying to use these in my code.

With the following minimal example:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    cout << chrono::utc_clock::now() << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

compiled using the following:

```
> /usr/local/gcc-11.1.0/bin/g++-11.1 -std=c++-20 main.cpp
```

gives the following error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:8:36: error: incomplete type ‘std::chrono::utc_clock’ used in 
    nested name specifier
    8 |         cout << chrono::utc_clock::now() << endl;
      |
```

I have looked into this error and it seems to usually stem from forward declarations. Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

I have also tried explicitly linking against the newly-built GCC 11 version of libstdc++.a:

```
/usr/local/gcc-11.1.0/bin/g++-11.1 -std=c++20 -L/usr/local/gcc-11.1.0/lib -lstdc++ main.cpp
```

But I get the same error message.

Some extra information:

```
> /usr/local/gcc-11.1.0/bin/g++-11.1 --version
```

gives the following output:

```
g++-11.1 (GCC) 12.0.0 20210427 (experimental)
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

which is unexpected to me since I'm expecting to see 11.1. I built this on MacOS and my `clang++` version is 12.0.5. Is this expected and could this be a potential source of the problem?

Also, [this website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#:%7E:text=Calendar) that shows compiler support for C++20 standard library features shows that GCC 11 has *partial* support for the updated `chrono`.

Lastly, I built GCC 11 from source using [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUa9w5rn3a8) as a reference.

Comment: It's my understanding that no compiler has full C++20 support yet; Visual Studio 2022 won't release until both the compiler AND Intellisense support it even if the compiler is compliant first.

Comment: still broken in gcc 12; according to the web site it should be supported in gcc 14, but I haven't used it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only partial C++20 chrono support is in gcc at this time.  [Here is the current state of the libstdc++ source code on this matter.](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/chrono#L1192)  This shows a simple forward declaration of `utc_clock`, and no definition, which is consistent with the error message you are seeing.

I *am* seeing more support for `file_clock`, including a low-level API to convert between `file_clock::time_point` and `system_clock::time_point`.  This is a significant addition.

Additionally I'm seeing support for the [calendrical types in C++20](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.cal) (e.g. `year_month_day`, etc.), which is what the release notes refers to.